# How to use array as ... type?

Tags: php, symfony, types

I want to call a method like that:

```php
public function to(Address|string ...$addresses) {}
```

I can call it with `$obj->to("my-address")`. But, when I want to give a list of address, I'm using:

```php
$myList = [ "address-1", "address-2" ];
$obj->to($myList);
```

But I get this error: `must be of type Symfony\Component\Mime\Address|string, array given`

Even if it's with `[]` :

[image]

How can I use array as parameters?

Comment: `Address|string|array`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense the method isn't from me but from Mailer. Can't edit it

Comment: Gotcha. make it $obj->to(...$myList); it will unpack the array into parameter list

Comment: Yes, Ar Rakin made an answer and it works, I'll accept it when I will be able to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `...` in the *call* to the function as well. That syntax has two complementary meanings, both [documented on the same page of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

- When used in the *declaration* of the function, as you have, it means "collect separate arguments (which must each be of the correct type, if specified) into an array"
- When used in *calling* a function, it means "pass the items of this array as separate arguments"

So:

```
$myList = [ "address-1", "address-2" ];
$obj->to(...$myList);
```

Means the same as:

```
$obj->to("address-1", "address-2");
```

And then the `...$addresses` in the function declaration makes that back into an array, checking that each item matches the type declaration `Address|string`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `...` to take every argument. You should spread your array before passing it to `to()`:

```php
$myList = [ "address-1", "address-2" ];
$obj->to(...$myList);
```